# Trying to assert existence of JSON object in an JSON Array using expect js with Karma suite

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, karma-runner

Hello guys so I am writing tests for my redux async actions and I am trying to assert that an object exists in an objet array but I cant get the test to run successfully even though the expected side effect occurs (saving data to firebase)

Here is my Test.

```
describe('Async Actions', () => {
        it('should upload supplier and dispatch ADD_SUPPLIER', (done)=> { /*Let Mocha know that this is asnyc test*/
          //mock a store
          const store = createMockStore({});

          //test supplier
          var testSupplier = {
            name: "new supplier",
            fact_sheet: "fact sheet",
            liability_sheet: "liability sheet",
            group: "group",
            service_lines: null,
            policies: null,
            rate_periods: null,
            rate_costs: null,
            contracts: null,
            cancellation_terms: null,
            deposit_terms: null,
            commission: 22,
            creation_date: moment().unix(),
            country: "SA",
            region: "Capetown",
            email: "mail@m.com",
            telephone: "2797179",
            website: "ww.ww.ww",
            category: "cat",
            rating: 100
          };

          //Do the async action
          store.dispatch(actions.startAddSupplier(testSupplier.name, testSupplier.fact_sheet, testSupplier.liability_sheet, testSupplier.group,
             testSupplier.commission, testSupplier.country, testSupplier.region, testSupplier.email, testSupplier.telephone, testSupplier.website, testSupplier.category, testSupplier.rating)).then(
               () => {
                    /*Assertions*/
             const actions = store.getActions(); //returns array of all actions fired on store

             expect(actions).toInclude({
              type: 'ADD_SUPPLIER'
             });


                 /*done to show test is done*/
                 done();
               }).catch(done);//if done is called with args it is assumed the test has failed
        });
      });
```

and this is what I get in the console as the error

```
FAILED TESTS:
  Actions
    Supplier Actions
      Async Actions
        ✖ should upload supplier and dispatch ADD_SUPPLIER
          Chrome 53.0.2785 (Mac OS X 10.12.0)
        Error: Expected [ { supplier: { cancellation_terms: null, category: 'cat', commission: 22, contracts: null, country: 'SA', creation_date: 1476087460, deposit_terms: null, email: 'mail@m.com', fact_sheet: 'fact sheet', group: 'group', id: '-KThemyhqrmDHuF_PV2H', liability_sheet: 'liability sheet', name: 'new supplier', policies: null, rate_costs: null, rate_periods: null, rating: 100, region: 'Capetown', service_lines: null, telephone: '2797179', website: 'ww.ww.ww' }, type: 'ADD_SUPPLIER' }, { key: '-KThemyhqrmDHuF_PV2H', type: 'SET_CURR_SUPPLIER' } ] to include { type: 'ADD_SUPPLIER' }
            at Object.assert [as default] (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/zacck/Documents/www/jtx/app/tests/actions/actions.test.jsx:1231:2), <anonymous>:20:9)
            at Expectation.toInclude (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/zacck/Documents/www/jtx/app/tests/actions/actions.test.jsx:1129:2), <anonymous>:190:26)
            at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/zacck/Documents/www/jtx/app/tests/actions/actions.test.jsx:47:2), <anonymous>:129:42)
```

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong I would appreciate any help whatsoever in finding the error.

Comment: Your test `testSupplier` doesn't have the the `id` property.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, 
So the issue here seems to be your understanding of what a unit test is, The code you are testing here dispatches an async method to the firebase instance. What is recommended rather would be to run the test with a mock response from the firebase instance, This would allow you to assert that your code responds correctly to a success response from firebase and a failure response thereby taking care of the unhappy paths. 
see this article here 
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests